# JavaScript heap out of memory when using @babel/standalone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I have react app I created using create-react-app. I am tying to take user code and evaluate it to render it.

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { transform } from "@babel/standalone";

const code =  transform("<span>Hello world</span>", {
  presets: ["@babel/react", "@babel/env"],
}).code

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
       <div>
         {eval(code)}
       </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This code gives me the following error in my terminal.

> FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

I am on a mac if that matters.

Comment: as I mentioned, the goal is to take user entered code and render it,

Comment: Right, should have read it more carefully, sorry

Comment: have you tried increasing the memory available to nodejs?

Comment: Yes, just increased to 8gb, no luck

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with a large react project, to fix it I made my large imports more specific.

For example:
from -

```
import {SelectBox} from 'somelibrary-react';
```

to -

```
import SelectBox from 'somelibrary-react/select-box';
```

more explanation you can find here:
[bundle size](https://material-ui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/)